# Creating a reference group to have equal sample sizes for Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: median, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am analyzing three years' worth of data. For some descriptive analysis, I want to know if there is a difference in the median between, $year_1$ and $year_2$ compared to $year_3$. To do this, I planned to average $year_1$ and $year_2$, creating a comparable 12-month reference group with $year_3$. I would then use the Wilcoxon signed rank test. Would this be a fair way to understand the data? The data is considered paired.

---

Thank you for your feedback. Let me first state, this is a preliminary analysis for a larger interrupted time series analysis in which autocorrelation is account for (using ARIMA).

Knowing this, would you still suggest the the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney two sampled ranked sum test (from this initial phase)? And if so, it is acceptable to have unequal groups ($n=24$ and $n=12$)?Also, the rate are coming from one distinct location, which is why I first instinctively considered them paired.

**Edit:** or is the creation of the (pre 12-month reference group still applicable)

I appreciate your continued input and support.

Comment: The Mann-Whitney Wilcoxon rank sum test **is not** properly a test for median difference. Rather, it is a test for evidence that $Pr(X_1 > X_2) \ne 0.5$. With additional stringent assumptions that groups 1 & 2 have (i) the same shape distribution, and (ii) the same variance, you can interpret a rejected rank sum null hypothesis as evidence for median difference (and for mean difference also). Tests for median difference in 2 or more groups are a variation of Pearson's $\chi^2$ test; e.g., see Conover's *Practical Nonparametric Statistics* section 4.3: The Median Test.

Comment: Also: Welcome to CV, Levi.

Comment: what about a test such as this? (https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/22/difference-of-medians-sas.html) **Quantile regression**

Answer (score 7):

The Wilcoxon signed-rank test, made almost obsolete by the [rank difference test](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2044-8317.1990.tb00939.x) is only for naturally paired data. You do not have paired data but rather data more suitable for the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney two-sample rank-sum test (although we are ignoring serial correlation in the data).  A better way to think about your problem is whether there is a non-flat time-trend, and it's best to use time as a continuous variable (e.g., year + fraction of year).  You can use a regression spline to relate time to response using a suitable model such as the proportional odds ordinal logistic model which generalizes the Wilcoxon two-sample test.  Resources for this model are [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).

If you have the time to take serial correlation into account you can easily use a Markov process with the proportional odds model.  For example a lag-1 analysis would be a first-order Markov process.  Details are in my course notes [here](http://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov.html).

Comment: I posted my last response incorrectly in an answer box thus it got deleted. But I wanted to make sure to say thank you for the response

Comment: Frank Harrell, thank you so much for that reference to the rank difference test!

Comment: Frank, how about something like the link below, Quantile regression. linearity, homoscedasticity, independence, or normality are not met?https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/22/difference-of-medians-sas.html

Comment: Quantile regression is not very efficient when sample sizes are not large.